# How to bind id to PrimeNg menu command

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I have a table with a list of items. I wanted to use PrimeNg Menu for dropdown menu options to navigate to other pages with the selected item id. What I wanted to do is, when I click on the menu items I wanted to bind id of the selected item.

my HTML looks like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items" class="animated fadeIn">
    <td>{{item.category}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.date}}</td>
    <td>
       <div>
           <p-menu #tableMenu [popup]="true" [model]="tableMenuItems" appendTo="body"></p-menu>
               <button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-ellipsis-v"
                   class="ui-button-secondary ui-button-rounded ui-button-transparent"
                   (click)="tableMenu.toggle($event)">
               </button>
       </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and my .ts

```
this.tableMenuItems = [
  {
    label: 'View Item', command: (event) => {
      // this.viewItemDetail() // here I wanted to bind item.id of the selected item and navigate to item detail page
    }
  },
  {
    label: 'Edit Item', command: (event) => {
      this.editItem() // here I wanted to bind item.id of the selected item and navigate to item edit page
    }
  },
];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can create a property to hold the current item and set the selected item at click event before invoke toggle method

*component*

```js
 selectedItem:any = null;
 ...
 ngOnInit(){

 this.tableMenuItems = [
  {
    label: 'View Item', command: (event) => {
       console.log(this.selectedItem);
      // this.viewItemDetail() // here I wanted to bind item.id of the selected item and navigate to item detail page
    }
  },
  {
    label: 'Edit Item', command: (event) => {
      this.editItem() // here I wanted to bind item.id of the selected item and navigate to item edit page
    }
  },
];
}
```

*template*

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of items" class="animated fadeIn">
    <td>{{item.category}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.date}}</td>
    <td>
       <div>
           <p-menu #tableMenu [popup]="true" [model]="tableMenuItems" appendTo="body"></p-menu>
               <button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-ellipsis-v"
                   class="ui-button-secondary ui-button-rounded ui-button-transparent"
                   (click)="selectedItem = item;tableMenu.toggle($event)">
               </button>
       </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: perfectly working and very easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Very good solution. I had apply this same concept to  PrimeNg Table and SplitButton using onDropdownClick event, like this:

Template:-

```
<p-splitButton [label]="getButtonText(element.status)" [model]="menuItens" icon="pi pi-plus-circle"
(onClick)="edit(element.identifier, element.title, element.status, element)" (onDropdownClick)="selectedItem = element"></p-splitButton>
```

Then in respective ts file component:

```
  this.menuItens = [
    {
      label: 'Print', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-print', command: () => {
        this.print(this.selectedItem.identifier, this.selectedItem.title, this.selectedItem);
      }
    },
    { separator: true },
    { label: 'Admin'}

  ];
```